# Filter producing wrong results Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a filter like :

```
$scope.Approved = $filter('filter')($scope.Summary.CorpEmployees, { locationId: item.Label, evaluationStatusId: '3' });
```

For some reason the filter is pulling the records whose `evaluationStatusId = 13`.
Can somebody pls explain why this is happening?
How can I make sure that my filter pulls only those records whose `evaluationStatusId = 3`

Comment: You're using a string, use a number

Comment: I tried number also but the result is same.

Comment: You have to use the strict equality parameter called "comparator" in the angularjs docs, otherwise it does a "contains" rather than an "equals" for the filter. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: It would look like this: `$scope.Approved = $filter('filter')($scope.Summary.CorpEmployees, { locationId: item.Label, evaluationStatusId: '3' }, true);`

Comment: @mhodges Thank u that worked.

Comment: @mhodges  if u can put that in the answer I can mark it as answer.

Comment: @rmkr Posted an answer. Glad my solution worked for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment:

> You have to use the strict equality parameter called "comparator" in
>   the angularjs docs, otherwise it does a "contains" rather than an
>   "equals" for the filter.

[See angular docs for filter here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

It would look like this:

```
$scope.Approved = $filter('filter')(
    $scope.Summary.CorpEmployees, 
    { locationId: item.Label, evaluationStatusId: '3' }, 
    true // <--- This is the parameter that forces strict equality
);
```